# Adjustable semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

Are there any production-grade implementations of Java Semaphore with possibility to adjust number of permits after semaphore is created?

Comment: What do you mean with "threshold"? The number of permits?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, number of permits.

Comment: Sure, as others have posted. Don't put any artificial limit on the count at creation time and then signal on whatever permits you want. If you want to add some, just do it. If you want to reduce, wait on the semaphore as many time as needed to remove permits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite give you 'existing production-grade', but I can give you 'existing source code', providing a thin wrapper *around* an existing production-grade implementation. How's that?

Essentially, you can *extend* Java's Semaphore class to acheive what you want. So, you're standing on the shoulders of giants.

1. To increase the number of permits X times, call [Semaphore.release(X)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release%28int%29)
2. To reduce the number of permits, call the **protected** method [Semaphore.reducePermits(X)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#reducePermits%28int%29) .

Item 2, the protected method, explains why you'll need to *extend* the Semaphore class.

For a full implementation and better explanation, see this blog entry:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190213082551/http://blog.teamlazerbeez.com/2009/04/20/javas-semaphore-resizing/

Comment: The blog post link is dead.